# Find the area of trapezium

Tags: geometry, area

$ABCD$ is a trapezium in which $AB||CD$. If $P$ is the point of intersection of diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ such that area of triangle $DPC=50cm^2$ and area of triangle $APB=32cm^2$.Then find area of trapezium $ABCD$.

I found that triangle APB and DPC are similar.The ratio of their sides is 4:5.The area of triangles DPC and CPB are equal.Please help me proceed.

Comment: similarity is involved

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know that the formula for the area of a trapezium is $\frac{h(a+b)}{2}$, where $h$ is the height and $a,b$ are lengths of parallel sides.

Comment: this would not work here.

Comment: Both of the results that you have found are useful. One more tool you need is “ratio of the areas of triangles having the same altitude is equal to the ratio of their bases”.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the diagram below:

[image: trapezoid_with_diagonals_and_altitude]

We are given that $\overline{AB} \parallel \overline{CD}$.  If two parallel lines are cut by a transversal, then alternate interior angles are congruent.  Thus, $\angle ABP \cong \angle CDP$ and $\angle CAB \cong \angle DCP$.  Therefore, $\triangle ABP \sim \triangle CDP$.

We are also given that the area of $\triangle ABP$ is $32~\text{cm}^2$, while the area of $\triangle CDP$ is $50~\text{cm}$.  Hence, the ratio of the areas of the similar triangles is 
$$\frac{A(ABP)}{A(CDP)} = \frac{32~\text{cm}^2}{50~\text{cm}^2} = \frac{16}{25}$$
The ratio of the areas of similar triangles is the square of the ratio of corresponding sides.  Thus, 
$$\frac{|AB|}{|CD|} = \frac{|AP|}{|CP|} = \frac{|BP|}{|DP|} = \sqrt{\frac{16}{25}} = \frac{4}{5}$$
Let $E$ be the foot of the altitude from point $P$ to $\overline{AB}$; let $F$ be the foot of the altitude from point $P$ to $\overline{CD}$.  Since all right angles are congruent, $\angle BEP \cong \angle DFP$.  Since we have also established that $\angle EBP \cong \angle FDP$, $\triangle BEP \sim \triangle DFP$.  Thus, 
$$\frac{|EP|}{|FP|} = \frac{|BP|}{|DP|} = \frac{4}{5}$$
The area of trapezoid $ABCD$ is 
\begin{align*}
A(ABCD) & = \frac{1}{2}(|AB| + |CD|)(|EP| + |FP|)\\ 
        & = \frac{1}{2}\left(|AB| + \frac{5}{4}|AB|\right)\left(|EP| + \frac{5}{4}|EP|\right)\\
        & = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{9}{4}|AB|\right)\left(\frac{9}{4}|EP|\right)\\
        & = \frac{81}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot |AB| \cdot |EP|\\
        & = \frac{81}{16} \cdot A(\triangle ABP)\\
        & = \frac{81}{16}(32~\text{cm}^2)\\
        & = 162~\text{cm}^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{A(DPC)}{A(ADC)}= \frac{PC}{AC}= \frac{5}{4}, $$  because the triangles have the same altitude over side AC
$$ \frac{50}{A(ADC)}= \frac{5}{9}$$
$$ A(ADC)= 90 cm^2$$
$$ \frac{A(APB)}{A(ABC)}=\frac{AP}{AC}=\frac{4}{9} $$
$$ A(ABC)=72 cm^2$$
$$ A(ABCD)= A(ADC)+A(ABC)= 90+72=162 cm^2 $$